# Print any utf-8 character to copy-paste from pdf

Tags: graphics, unicode, copy-paste

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\MyBrand}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3em]{myBrand}%
}
\begin{document}
I always use \MyBrand , it's the best!
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following pdf:

[image: I always use MyBrnd, it’s the best!]

I want to be able to copy the complete text from the pdf to a text editor (Notpad, Word, …), including the text in the image.

When I mark the sentence in a pdf-Viewer (Adobe Acrobat) and copy it, I get "I always use , it’s the best!". But I want "I always use MyBrnd, it’s the best!".

So added an invisible tikz-layer fitted to the image width, in which I can type my text (because I used the resizebox, the text can even be very long):

```
\newcommand{\MyBrand}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3em]{myBrand}%
    \hspace*{-3em}%
    \resizebox{3em}{!}{%
        \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0]{myBrand};%
    }%
}
```

With the added tikz node I get "I always use myBrand, it’s the best!". That is a start, but I want "I always use MyBrnd, it’s the best!".

If I change the node to `\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0]{myBrnd};`, I get garbage like "I always use myBrnd, it’s the best!" when compiling with XeLaTeX and nothing with pdfLaTeX (inputenc Error).

How can I print ANY utf-8 character (even if the font doesn't have a symbol for it) for the purpose of copying it from the pdf into a text editor (which hopefully has an appropriate font)? Is there a solution for both Xe- and pdfLaTeX?

Again: I don't care if the symbol doesn't show up or shows as a placeholder… as long as it can be copied by marking the text in a pdf-Viewer and pasted to a text editor (where I can chose a font supporting all utf-8 characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the accsupp package. But it won't work in every pdf-viewer, e.g. sumatra doesn't copy it.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,accsupp}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\MyBrand}{%
\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,unicode,ActualText={MyBrnd}}%
    \includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image}%
\EndAccSupp{}%    
}
\begin{document}

I always use \MyBrand, it's the best! 

\end{document}
```

### Edit

as discovered in the comments it doesn't work if the picture is a bitmap (e.g. jpg or png). In this case one work-around is to a glyph, e.g.

```
  \rlap{.}\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image.png}%
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with Acrobat Reader XI and it doesn't work (neither compiling with XeLaTeX, nor with pdfLaTeX). It just copy-pasted "I always use , it’s the best!" as if there were only the image. With what pdf-viewer did it work for you?

Comment: Adobe reader dc. The example is for pdflatex, with lualatex you need also luatex85, i didn't try with xelatex. Do you have a current tex system?

Comment: Yes, I have a full texlive 2017 installation (updated just now). I'm compiling with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`. I tried opening it with Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge too, but it didn't copy anything from the "ActualText".

Comment: I just installed Adobe Reader DC and I couldn't copy anything "from" the image as well. Just "I always use , it's the best!", as before :-(

Comment: You really should use nonstopmode -- or if you do you should check the log ;-). My code works with a development version of hyperref. But I don't have the time now to check which commit enable the handling of this unicode range.

Comment: The log states `Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 13.`. So I guess it should be working?! Anyway, thank you for your answer. In that case I shall wait for updates or other approaches :-)

Comment: Don't you get an error about an unset character?

Comment: No, there are no errors whatsoever and nothing about an unset character…

Comment: Ah sorry, the error was from something else. I now retested and it works fine also in with the normal hyperref for me. What happens if you do in the reader "ctrl A ctrl C"? Does this copy correctly to the clipboard?

Comment: When I copied your code I always changed `\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image}` to `\includegraphics[width=3em]{myBrand}` (inserting the correct picture). I now compiled it with `example-image` and this works. Now I have the copyable character, but not the right image…

Comment: It seems, that AccSupp needs some characters to replace (like the "example-image" has). Using `\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,unicode,ActualText={MyBrnd}}% 
 \includegraphics[width=3em]{myBrand}%
 \hspace*{-3em}%
  \resizebox{3em}{!}{%
  \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0]{myBrand};%
 }
\EndAccSupp{}%` as `\MyBrand` works perfectly (in pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX). Thank you. Could you modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: I added an edit.